# "Everyone except external users" - no results found

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, authentication, sharepoint-permissions, everyone

Until recently, I was able to grant access to all authenticated users in my tenant through the `Everyone except external users` role. This morning, I get a `No results found` message.

Anything changed overnight?

[image: Everyone except external users - No results found]

Answer (score 0):

Solved - it was a tenant-wide setting change. Not confirmed directly, but probably: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps#-showeveryoneexceptexternalusersclaim